# Multiple user role to a custom post type

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, user-roles

I've created a CPT, issue_chapter, and a new user translator. Now how a dropdown can be added with list of translators in this CPT? "Author" and "Translator" both should be there.

I have created a metabox

```
add_meta_box( 
        'translator', 
        'Translator', 
        'zc_translator_meta_box_callback', 
        'issue_chapter', 
        'advanced', 
        'high' );

function zc_translator_meta_box_callback( $post ) {
$role = 'translator';

$query_users_ids_by_role = array(
    'field' => 'id',
    'role' => $role
);

$array_of_users_ids = get_users( $query_users_ids_by_role );

$users_ids_list = implode( ',',$array_of_users_ids );

$query_for_dropdown = array(
    'include' => $user_ids_list,
);

wp_dropdown_users( $query_for_dropdown );
}
```

Now how to save the value?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution. Thank you.

```
add_meta_box( 'the_translator',  
        'Translator', 
        'zc_the_translator_callback', 
        'issue_chapter', 
        'advanced', 
        'high' 
    );

add_action( 'save_post', 'zc_save_the_translator_data' );

function zc_the_translator_callback( $post ){
wp_nonce_field( 'zc_save_the_translator_data', 'zc_the_translator_meta_box_nonce' );
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_the_translator_value_key', true );
?>

<label for="zc_the_translator_field">Translator</label>
<select name="zc_the_translator_field" id="zc_the_translator_field">
    <option value="0">-- Select Translator --</option>
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'role' => 'translator'
    );
    $user_list = get_users($args);
    foreach( $user_list as $user ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $user->ID; ?>" <?php selected($value, $user->ID); ?>><?php echo $user->user_nicename ; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>

<?php   
}

function zc_save_the_translator_data( $post_id ){
if( !isset( $_POST['zc_the_translator_meta_box_nonce']) ){
    return;
}
if( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['zc_the_translator_meta_box_nonce'], 'zc_save_the_translator_data' ) ){
    return;
}
if( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ){
    return;
}
if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ){
    return;
}
if( !isset( $_POST['zc_the_translator_field']) ){
    return;
}
$my_data = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['zc_the_translator_field'] ) ;
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_the_translator_value_key', $my_data );
}
```

To retrieve the value use this:

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_the_translator_value_key', true ); ?>
```